# TcpClient throws SocketException

Tags: c#, tcp

I got the following code:

```
public static readonly IPEndPoint RootNode = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("213.226.18.82"), 8333);

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(RootNode);
}
```

This throws a `SocketException` with the message `The requested address is not valid in its context`.
Now whats strange is that this code works:

```
public static readonly IPEndPoint RootNode = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("213.226.18.82"), 8333);

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

    tcpClient.Connect(RootNode);
}
```

What is the difference here?

Comment: A connection has two endpoints.  A local and a remote.  The first code should be setting up a local endpoint, while the second code is setting up the remote endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx it talks about this constructor:

> TcpClient(IPEndPoint): Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and binds it to the specified local endpoint.

So here it says that it will bind it to the **local** adress, like you were listening on some port maybe. The `Connect()` command will connect you to a **remote** endpont. That should be the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and binds it to the specified local endpoint.

The [Connect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6kc0793(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Connects the client to a remote TCP host using the specified remote network endpoint.